# What is the mistake in creating a SAN

Tags: ssl, tls

I issued a TLS certificate and indicated the name of the SAN file using ext, but when I go to the chrome site it gives an error, what did I do wrong? Site - https://seeklay.icu Ext -

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = tls.seeklay.icu
DNS.2 = seeklay.icu
```

Comment: Chrome shows what's causing the error, the Certificate Authority (`NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`).  See [Google's results](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=jJJ7Xb79Dsuy5gK4nqygDA&q=NET%3A%3AERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID&oq=NET%3A%3AERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID&gs_l=psy-ab.3...551.551..707...0.0..0.103.103.0j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.dMsYAOa5dw8&ved=0ahUKEwi-85GH7c3kAhVLmVkKHTgPC8QQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)

Comment: if you trigger a warning, another appears that there is no SAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificate has *multiple copies* of various extensions, some of then even having different values. Here's what GnuTLS `certtool -i` has to say about it:

```
$ certtool -i < SU1482305.crt
X.509 Certificate Information:
        Version: 3
        Serial Number (hex): 11e2438da11b3338655874e3a4104cfaabc410e0
        Issuer: CN=ACA ECC ROOT G1,OU=alternativeca.us/ca/ecc/g1,O=AlternativeCA inc.,L=Phoenix,ST=Arizona,C=US
        Validity:
                Not Before: Fri Sep 13 10:54:33 UTC 2019
                Not After: Fri Jul 14 10:54:33 UTC 2023
        Subject: CN=seeklay.icu,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=US
        Subject Public Key Algorithm: RSA
        Algorithm Security Level: Medium (2048 bits)
                Modulus (bits 2048):
                        8d
                Exponent (bits 24):
        Extensions:
                Authority Key Identifier (not critical):
                        directoryName: CN=seeklay.icu,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=US
                        serial: 13fec21b5f7198cdb35f95b455263b92078b3b24
                Basic Constraints (not critical):
                        Certificate Authority (CA): FALSE
                Key Usage (not critical):
                        Digital signature.
                        Non repudiation.
                        Key encipherment.
                        Data encipherment.
                Subject Alternative Name (not critical):
                        DNSname: tls.seeklay.icu
                        DNSname: seeklay.icu
warning: more than one AKI extension
                Authority Key Identifier (not critical):
                        directoryName: CN=ACA ECC ROOT G1,OU=alternativeca.us/ca/ecc/g1,O=AlternativeCA inc.,L=Phoenix,ST=Arizona,C=US
                        serial: 5810507f10d39ff8bce24d6258e133e38a56c757
warning: more than one basic constraint
                Basic Constraints (not critical):
                        Certificate Authority (CA): FALSE
warning: more than one key usage extension
                Key Usage (not critical):
                        Digital signature.
                        Non repudiation.
                        Key encipherment.
                        Data encipherment.
warning: more than one SKI extension
                Subject Alternative Name (not critical):
                        DNSname: tls.seeklay.icu
                        DNSname: seeklay.icu
        Signature Algorithm: RSA-SHA256
```

As you can see, all extensions are duplicated and the Authority Key Identifier even references two different CA certs.